# how can I get the 'id' of 4 <div> and 4 <input type="text">

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

This should be easy but after studying the DOM and perusing related posts on SO I'm still not there.

I have one outermost div that has, nested within it, 4 divs.  And each of the 4 nested divs has one input type="text" nested inside.

And I have a single onclick added to that outermost containing div, so that clicking on any of the 4 nested divs or input type="text" elements invokes the one 'onclick' handler.

And in the onclick handler I need to get the id, name and value of the 4 text inputs and the 4 nested divs too.

Here's the code.

```
  <div class="itemlistRowContainer" id="topmostDiv ID" onclick="handleRowClick(this);"
         name="itemlistRowContainer Div name" value="itemlistRowContainer Div Value">

      <div class="itemListRowElementLeftMost" name="itemListRowElementLeftMost Div name"
         value="itemListRowElementLeftMost Div value">Item<br />

        <input type="text" size="30" maxlength="50" id="itemName_id"
           name="itemName" value="$itemname" readonly="readonly"></input>

      </div>

        // 3 more divs and nested text input pairs not shown for brevity
  </div>
```

Here's the onclick event handler -- notice above that in the outermost div, I pass 'this' to the onclick() handler, which from various SO posts I read, I believe 'this'  passes the outermost div itself to the onclick handler:

```
   function handleRowClick(theElement)
   {

        var childNodes = theElement.childNodes;
        var numChildNodes = childNodes.length;

        alert("handleRowClick: childNodes array has length = " + numChildNodes);


      for(i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++)
      {

        alert("The DOM element " + i + " has innerHTML = " + childNodes[i].innerHTML + ", " 
          + "nodeName = " + childNodes[i].nodeName + ", "
          + "nodeType = " + childNodes[i].nodeType + ", "
          + "nodeValue = " + childNodes[i].nodeValue + ", "
          + "parentNode = " + childNodes[i].parentNode + ", "
          + "childNodes = " + childNodes[i].childNodes + ", "
          + "attributes = " + childNodes[i].attributes + ", "
          + "name = " + childNodes[i].name + ", "
          + "value = " + childNodes[i].value + ", "
          + "id = " + childNodes[i].id);
     }
```

The first alert() above shows me that there are 9 total array elements in the childNodes array.

When the 'for' loop executes, it tells me there are 2 types of DOM elements in the array:

There are 5 reported as:  **nodeName=#text, nodeType = 3,** and **value=id=name=undefined**

And there are 4 childNode[] elements reported as: **nodeName=DIV, nodeType = 1,** and AGAIN -- **value=name=id=undefined.**

In my opinion -- it looks like in the onclick handler, I'm correctly being passed the 4 nested divs (nodeType 1) and the 4 read-only text fields, nodeType=#text, nodeType=3, input type=text.

And then the 9th and final element reported by the 'for' loop is -- one extra **nodeName=#text** element (nodeType = 3) that I have no clue what that is -- if it was the outermost div then it would have nodeType=1 and **nodeName=div** like the 4 inner divs.

Fine and dandy.  But then why the heck are the id, the name and value unable to help me figure out which is which?

The innerHTML, for the DIV nodes, has the html tags for the input type=text nested within but I have no plans to parse it -- the output (in the alert() box of the 'for' loop above)  for a DIV node is this:

```
    The DOM element 1 has innerHTML = Item<br>
        <input size="30" maxlength="50" id="itemName_id" name="itemName" 
                       value="f's first item" readonly="readonly" 
                      type="text">
          ,  nodeName = DIV, nodeType = 1, nodeValue = null, 
              parentNode = [object HTMLDivElement], childNodes = [object  
              NodeList], attributes = [object NamedNodeMap], 
               name = undefined, value = undefined, id =
```

My question is, when my onclick handler is called I need to get the id, name, value of each of the 4 contained DIVs and the 4 contained input type=text elements -- how?
Why are they all 'undefined' because it sure looks like I'm getting access to the 4 nested divs and the 4 text fields when my onclick() handler is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your outermost div has 4 child divs. So `theElement.childNodes.length` should give you 4. These are the 4 nodeName = DIV, nodeType = 1 results that you see. Each input element is a child of the inner div. `theElement.childNodes` will not return the input elements. The mysterious nodeType = 3 entries are text nodes. Consider the following fragment

```
<div>
   <div>text in innerdiv</div>
   text in outer div   
</div>
```

The outer div has two child nodes - a nested div and the text `text in outer div`

try using

```
function handleRowClick(theElement)
{

    var childDivs = theElement.getElementsByTagName("div");
    var childInputs = theElement.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(i = 0; i < childDivs.length; i++)
    {
        //process child divs here
    }

    for (i=0; i<childInputs.length; i++ )
    {
        //process child inputs here
    }
 }
```

Comment: +1, thank you, very clean, I would not have come to that, thanks.  Question -- will the childInputs have their id, name and value set correctly as I need those to process the click event?  I'm assuming that the childInputs will be the input type=text elements, surely then they will have id, name and value accessible in your for loop above?

Comment: Yes, `childInputs` will contain every `<input>` element inside the outer div irrespective of how deep they are nested and even if they have the same name or id or value.

Comment: That did me -- thanks for your help -- I have many many rows of the above '4 divs and 4 text read-only' rows that appear on the page and will now be able to successfully determine which row was clicked -- I have to modify the CSS styles in response -- thanks for your help, I very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `parent()` and `siblings` and `children()` function of jquery.E.g.
`$('@idOfOuterDiv').children().html()` this wud give the inner div content.Follow same way u get all the conents

Comment: I have marching orders -- no jquery otherwise I'm there.  Not my choice this time, I very much appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HTMLElement.getAttribute(attributeName)` to get attribute values

Comment: thanks for taking some time to try to help me with this -- I appreciate it.